# Why does MediaWwiki take a long time to load the page

Tags: php, performance, mediawiki

I am using MediaWiki 1.21.2, I have set it up successfully and I am able to access it on localhost.

The problem is that it takes a long time (approximately 5-10 minutes ) to load first time everyday, even if I make any change in LocalSettings.php then also it takes so much time to reload the page.

Comment: looks like its building up the cache, can you confirm this by killing the caches (file, php and mysql) and try again?

Comment: while reloading it doesn't take time ,i tried this with clearing the cache of browser

Comment: I was taking about mysql-query-cache, php cache and maybe a filebased cache from the system. Generating those caches once required time but once they've been build they significally increase pagespeed

Comment: so what i can do for that, i am not familiar with mysql-query-cache, php cache.

Comment: MediaWiki without proper caching set up is VERY slow. You should read this first: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Cache

Then I would recommend setting up Varnish: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Varnish_caching

Comment: still didn't get my answer ............

Answer (score 2):

This is not exactly the answer of my question, But it helps me so i am sharing this with you.

To increase the performance of MediaWiki we need to do caching of following 4 things.

1. PHP caching
2. Object caching
3. Localization caching
4. Page caching

You can refer to the following manual page
 https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Cache

Answer (score -1):

Maybe your problem is the same as mine, my solution:

1. Open the file: 
   root / includes / Wiki.php
2. Ctrl + F: 
   $this->triggerJobs();
3. Change to: 
   // $this->triggerJobs();
4. Save and test.

Comment: Ugh. Don't do that. You want to set `$wgJobRunRate = 0` in LocalSettings.php.